# Feed Element Custom Lightning Component Toggling issue

Tags: lightning

I have a replicate component of Feed elements that fetch feeds/feed comments in collapsed and expanded view.

In collapsed view, I am having a problem in collapsing/Expanding posts at a same time.
As I am showing all the posts in aura iteration, and toggling posts one by one on pressing expanding button as shown in picture 1 below. I am having a hard time doing a thing like if I expand one post and I expand another post without collapsing the first one so both of them should remain expanded until and unless I collapse any of them, because I am toggling the posts on the basis of same function(If post is hide then show it, if post in shown then hide it). When I press expand/collapsed button it toggles on the basis of my toggling function. Moreover, I have put an aura if condition in Lightning Component to render just the posts whose expanding button I am pressing up. Some basic code explanation for guidance has been shown below.

```js
    toggleAction : function(component, event, secId) {
            var acc = component.find(secId);
            for(var cmp in acc) {
                console.log(acc[cmp]);
                $A.util.toggleClass(acc[cmp], 'slds-show');  
                $A.util.toggleClass(acc[cmp], 'slds-hide');  
            }
        },
```

Component
Component Excerpt:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.feedItems}" var="item" indexVar="indx">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!item.id == v.feedElementId}">
        <!--only expanded post will be shown here-->
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.feedComments}" var="commentItems" indexVar="commentVar">
            <!--!item.capabilities.comments.page.items-->
            <aura:if isTrue="{!and(commentItems.feedElement.id == item.id, commentItems.threadParentId == null)}">
                <!--comments related to expanded post will be shown here-->
            </aura:if>
        </aura:iteration>
    </aura:if>
</aura:iteration>
```

For Example, if I have 5 posts and I expand the first one. Then I don't collapse it and expand the second post as well.
So in my current scenario, all of them become collapsed and the second post will be expanded. But I want it to be like if I expand the first post and also expand the second post without collapsing the first one so both the posts should be expanded until and unless I collapse any of them.